# How to start WildFly8 server (in OpenShift)

Tags: java, websocket, openshift, wildfly-8

This question is in relation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600845/web-socket-disconnecting-on-openshift-with-wildfly-8-2-1).

I want to implement the new HTML5 WebSocket feature in WildFly 8.2.1 in OpenShift. My previous post has my java class (which is the server) and a html client and the pom.xml file. The problem was whenever I made opened the MyTest.html, the WebSocket connection would immediately disconnect.

I was reading [this article](https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-websocket-web-applications-with-jboss-wildfly/) on how to implement WebSockets on OpenShift using WildFly 8.2.1. It said that you actually have to start the wildfly server by action hooks and by doing so in the terminal. I have no clue what they are talking about. Could you please assist me in this manner as I am new to this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you should continue with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600845/web-socket-disconnecting-on-openshift-with-wildfly-8-2-1). I see that there's some confusion about that the server needs to be bound to port 8080 and the client should be connecting to 8000 when using websockets.

Second, [the article you are referring](https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-websocket-web-applications-with-jboss-wildfly/) is using a DIY cartridge to run the WilDFly server. There are better options how to do that now - using one of the available OpenShift cartridges ([WilDfly 8.2.1](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_type/cart!jboss-wildfly-8) is among them). That way you don't need to worry about the initial setup that much. If you have not used one of the WildFly cartridges, [this guide](https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-getting-started.html) could be helpful.

I think, that after following up the above, you may no longer need this, but as you've asked, [**here**](https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-server-management.html) is a guide on how to manage WildFly server on OpenShift (that includes suspend, resume). You will need to use `rhc port-forward <your_wildfly_app>` in order to access it using your web browser. (The WildFly admin runs on the 9990 port.)

Comment: I read this guide: https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-getting-started.html. But I couldn't find anything about websockets and how to configure the server for that. So do I have to go to my admin (as you have said) and manually start the server or to make it available so the client can access it at port 8000?

Comment: I read the tutorials and I (am using eclipse) and it generated a war file for me, and I put it under /deployments as one of the article says. But I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Do I have to go to Jboss modules as your article points out, and manually add my APIs and the java web socket class there?

Comment: If you use a WildFly cartridge, there is no need to manually start the server afterwards the cartridge is started. You can check that by visiting the application URL it presents to you. I will comment re the the endpoint connect/disconnect problem in your other question...