# Where does @serverendpoint path get mapped (Websockets)

Tags: java, websocket, openshift, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have the following @serverendpoint path for a websocket that I am using with the spring framework:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/serverendpoint", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
```

1. My first question is say I have a website with the url `www.example.com`. Where does the serverendpoint with path serverendpoint get mapped? Can I access my serverendpoint at `wss://example.com:$PORT/currentpage.html/serverendpoint`? Or is this the wrong way.
2. I have a Wildfly 10 server running. [Based on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600845/web-socket-disconnecting-on-openshift-with-wildfly-8-2-1), I was told to use the following Uri: `var wsUri = "wss://" + document.location.hostname + ":8443" + document.location.pathname + "/../serverendpoint";`. However, when I do so, in Google Chrome, I receive the following error:

`WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.`

My console.log prints that the websocket has been connected, but then I immediately get the above error. What am I doing wrong?

As per the Wildfly server log, I know the serverendpoint was mapped:

```
[io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) UT026003: Adding annotated server endpoint class com.voice2.spring.web.controller.serverendpoint for path /serverendpoint
```

So how do I connect to this sever endpoint?

Here is my project file hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Uri path to use to connect to Spring WebSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301304/what-uri-path-to-use-to-connect-to-spring-websocket)

Comment: @ArtemBilan sir, is there a solution to this problem. I asked the duplicate question you mentioned only beacuas no one was answering this. So I asked the other question, rephrasing this question and asking a simple one about what path to use on the client side to connect to the websocket