# What Uri path to use to connect to Spring WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a WebSocket Application using Spring MVC that I have defined as per [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support) tutorial. The file that configures the WebSocket is the following:

```
package com.myapp.spring.web.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.SpringConfigurator;


@ServerEndpoint(value="/serverendpoint", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)

public class serverendpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen () {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage (Session session, String message) throws IOException {

        if (message.equals("ping")) {
//            return "pong"
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("pong");
        }
        else if (message.equals("close")) {
            handleClose();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("JAVA: Received from client: "+ message);
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(message);
        String res = mc.action();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(res);
        return res;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose() {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now disconnected...");
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Question is if I have a Javascript client trying to connect to this WebSocket, what Uri should I use if the WebSocket is mapped at "/serverendpoint" as seen from the above @serverendpoint annotation?

```
var wsUri = "??????"
var webSocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

***What should wsUri be?***

Here is my Spring MVC project hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the same address for your server running the http port